# Blender geometry node use sequence image

Tags: geometry-nodes, image-sequence

I search to use image sequence in geometry node with image texture node.

[image]

The Input Frame should be able to do this, but I can't get it to work.

This is a simple geonode setup for use texture to selection :

[image]

With a single image it work, but I don't know how to match the frame range with my sequence ;

[image]

Someone have any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I usually do it like this:

1. I add an *Image Texture* node in the *Geometry Nodes Editor*. For the *Frame* input I use the *Scene Time* node's *Frame* output. Then I click *Open* to import an image sequence.

[image: image texture node]

2. In the *Open Image* dialogue box I select all images of the sequence I want to import. I make sure that in the sidepanel (hit <kbd>N</kbd> to bring it up) the option *Detect Sequences* is enabled. Although I think this option should provide it works even if you only select the first image - it doesn't. Then I click *Open Image*.

[image: open image dialogue]

And that's all. If I now play the animation, the image sequence plays as well. If you only have opened the first image or didn't enable *Detect Sequences* you can still make it work:

1. Go to the *Image Editor* and select the first frame of the sequence in the dropdown menu at the top.
2. In the sidepanel (<kbd>N</kbd>) change *Source* from *Single Image* to *Image Sequence*. Then you can change the *Frame* number to the length of your image sequence.

[image: image editor options]

Now it should work even if you just opened the first image or the *Detect Sequences* option was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon's answer is right! I will just add a little thing that tripped me:

The ImageSequence `offset` is not automatically calculated from the image data block in GN if you use the `frame` input:

[image: ImageSequence_opts]

So you just have to add the offset yourself:

[image: AddOffset]

The same thing applies to `cyclic`. Use a modulo node set to the total frame count **before** adding the offset

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how to make it work,

Open the image sequence in the panel Texture Properties, and frame range on the node work :o

[image]

On the other hand I don't understand how it makes the link with the node...